# MERN App - Recommended ways to upload, store, and retrieve images?

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, storage, mern

I have an app using MERN stack. What i want to do is to allow the user to upload images from their local machine, save that image, and display it on the website. What would be the recommended way to do this? It seems as if GridFS and MongoDB is an option but from what I am reading, storing images files directly in a database isn't recommended

Answer (score 0):

Storing images directly to DB is not recommended. Instead, you can use some third party libraries like multer that store images in the folder and generate a path for you to access that image which you can save in db.

Another approach is to use third-party services like Cloudinary or S3 bucket to save images and they will in return give you the URLs and you can save those Urls in DB.